# Neural Network behaving odd after the first iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science

I am new to the realm of neural networks and just going through my first actual working sample, using the hand written digits MNIST dataset. I have written a code which as far as I can think should be working (at least to some level), but I cannot figure out what makes it get stuck right after reading the first training sample. My code is the following:

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
import numpy as np

def relu(x):
    return (x > 0) * x

def relu_deriv(x):
    return x > 0

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data();

images = x_train[0:1000].reshape(1000, 28*28)
labels = y_train[0:1000]

test_images = x_test[0:1000].reshape(1000, 28*28)
test_labels = y_test[0:1000]

# converting the labels to a matrix
one_hot_labels = np.zeros((len(labels),10))
for i,j in enumerate(labels):
    one_hot_labels[i][j] = 1
labels = one_hot_labels


alpha = 0.005
hidden_size = 5 # size of the hidden layer

# initial weight matrixes
w1 = .2 * np.random.random(size=[784, hidden_size]) - .1
w2 = .2 * np.random.random(size=[hidden_size, 10]) - .1

for iteration in range(1000):
    error = 0
    for i in range(len(images)):
        layer_0 = images[i:i+1]
        layer_1 = relu(np.dot(layer_0, w1))
        layer_2 = np.dot(layer_1, w2)
        delta_2 = (labels[i:i+1] - layer_2)
        error += np.sum((delta_2) ** 2)
        delta_1 = delta_2.dot(w2.T) * relu_deriv(layer_1)
        w2 += alpha * np.dot(layer_1.T, delta_2)
        w1 += alpha * np.dot(layer_0.T, delta_1)
    print("error: {0}".format(error))
```

What happens is in the first iteration there is obviously a large error, and it gets corrected to 1000 after that, but then no matter how many more iterations, it just gets stuck on that forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't normalized the image data. The image data has value ranging from 0 to 255. Because of these large values the updates to the weights become large resulting in very large weights after the first iteration. You can normalize the image data as follows.

```
images = x_train[0:1000].reshape(1000, 28*28)
images = images / 255
labels = y_train[0:1000]

test_images = x_test[0:1000].reshape(1000, 28*28)
test_images = test_images / 255
test_labels = y_test[0:1000]
```

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly the problem :)